# upload .txt file into textarea in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I'm new to Django. I've made textareas for a website, using the django forms widget.

I want to add a fileupload to be able to upload a .txt file that will be inserted into the text area. How do I go about it?

I've checked the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

How do I incorporate this code within what I've already written?

forms.py

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    textInput = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Input text...',
            'id': 'input1'
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = Post #import Post model from home models.py
        fields = {'textInput',} #comma required to ensure tuple capability
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT) #default .CASCADE
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) #data saved into db
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name='home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm

        posts = Post.objects.all()
        args = {'form': form, 'posts': posts}

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)


    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False) #saves data (thanks to the model form)
            #comit is false as object still needs to be modified
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['textInput'] #anticipates SQL injection
            #return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should append `forms.FileField` to take ability to use Django framework uploading mechanism.

Any Django form has its `lifecycle` while request is processing. When user upload .txt file, you can catch this in `save` method like this:

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    text_file = forms.FileField()
    ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        ...
        # check if text_file contains content
        text_file_data = self.cleaned_data.get("text_file")
        ...
        if text_file_content:
            # self.instance is instance of "Post" model
            self.instance.post = text_file_content
        ...
        return super().save(commit)
```

Comment: thanks Pavel. Where does text_file_content come from?

Comment: I am not sure, but likely `self.cleaned_data.get("text_file")` will return InMemory storage and you should parse conent from that